# How to make MSBuild emit commands?

Tags: msbuild

I have an application which is built using `msbuild` and on Powershell.
Consider that MSBuild files are all over the place and many. I see often many tasks like:

```
<Target Name="MyTarget" Inputs="..." Outputs="...">
  <Message Text="Compiling..."/>
  <Exec Command="..."/>
</Target>
```

I would like to have MSBuild print our the command he is executing. You in the `Command` argument of these `Exec` tags there are complex strings with references to many variables using this syntax `$(Variable)`. I need to see the command that `msbuild` is executing.

#### Duplicates

Please note how this is not a duplicate question with regards to the many posts published about getting output printed by `msbuild`. Here I do not care about command output, I want to see the command and not its output.

Comment: I guess you could either create a property and first print the value of the property and then exeucte the value of the property, or you could make a custom msbuild task which does print the command given before executing it.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use the command in a property and print it with `Message` task

```
<Target Name="MyTarget" Inputs="..." Outputs="...">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Command>dir.exe /w</Command>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Message Text="Running command: '$(Command)'" Importance="high" />
  <Exec Command="$(Command)"/>
</Target>
```

Or:

Prefix the `Exec` commands with `echo`:

```
 <Exec Command="echo command..."/>
```